# Can't connect to Azure Sql Database from SSMS: "The public data endpoint on this server is not accessible..."

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

When trying to connect to my Azure Sql Database from SSMS on my client machine, I get the following error:
*The public data endpoint on this server is not accessible. To connect to this server, use the Private Endpoint from inside your virtual network*

[image]

My Azure Sql server firewall settings seem to be correct:

[image]
In the 1st rule, the start & end IP addresses are equal to the IP address of my azure web app, which btw manages to connect ok. 
In the 2nd rule, the start & end IP addresses are equal to the IP address of my client machine.

The problem started a couple of days ago, until then I had no problem connecting from SSMS.

Some additional points:

- Using an online open port checker, I verified that port 1433 is open on the domain <mysqlserver>.database.windows.net
- On the same client machine, in the Windows ODBC adminstrator, I have a DSN that points to the same database - it connects ok. But if I define a new DSN, with the same settings, it receives the same error as in SSMS above.
- I don't know if this is related, but when I try to change any of the settings in the Azure Sql server "Firewalls and virtual networks" page (photographed above), most of the times the changes aren't saved. The activity log shows that the operation timed out. I reported this issue in [the MS forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4f0c7b24-9340-4c1e-828f-3e888592aae4/cant-change-azure-sql-server-firewall-settings) but haven't yet received any helpful reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After receiving no help either here or in the MS forum, I had no choice but to pay for an Azure support plan. I reported the issue and they fixed the problem from their side. I can now connect to my database with SSMS.

I understand that it was a bug in the Azure platform. This is the message I received from them:

*We recently rolled out a feature called Deny Public Endpoint Access which is enabled/disabled at the server level.  However, we missed a state (Deactivate) in the MS workflow.  This means that if a server contains deactivated instances and customer attempts to enable/disable Public Endpoint Access (customer facing property name is PublicNetworkAccess) on the server, the workflow will become stuck as it is unable to handle deactivated instances.*
*We currently have a fix checked in for this already: http://sqlbuvsts01:8080/Main/SQL%20Server/_versionControl/changeset/1410047.  However, with no fly zone right now, we are figuring out how to get this fix deployed as soon as possible*